# Angular 14 and auth0: How do I add a url path to the api that doesn't get Authorisation added to it Every time I make a request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auth0

Below id the current code I have which authorizes every endpoint /* but I want to specify a specific endpoint that I can bypass.

```
this.authClientConfig.set({
              domain: auth0Config.domain,
              clientId: auth0Config.clientId,
              useRefreshTokens: true,
              authorizationParams: {
                redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
                audience: auth0Config.audience,
              },
              httpInterceptor: {
                allowedList: [
                  {
                    uri: `${appConfig.baseApiUrl}*`,
                    tokenOptions: {
                      authorizationParams: {
                        // The attached token should target this audience
                        audience: auth0Config.audience
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
             });
```